# Detect if dragged element is overlapping another

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable, intersection-observer

I have two elements with the class `.panel`. They can have an additional class `.panel--expanded`. I also have an element, which is `draggable`. What I want to do is to detect, if the draggable element is overlapping the panel element **without** the `.panel--expanded` class. I tried to solve this with the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). What I expect was, when I set the `root` as the panel without the expanded class, the target callback should throw the alert, if dragging over the panel **without** the expanded class. On the other way, it should not throw the alert, if I drag it over the panel **with** the expanded class. Seems that I understood something wrong from how the `IntersectionObserver` works. Is it even possible with it, or did I miss something? At the moment, no alert appears in both cases.

Here is my snippet:

```js
let target = document.querySelector('.draggable');

let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
     if (entry.isIntersecting) {
       alert('OVERLAPPING!');
     }
  }); 
};

let options = {
  root: document.querySelector('.panel:not(.panel--expanded)')
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
observer.observe(target);
```

```css
.panel {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  width: 500px;
}

.panel--expanded {
  background-color: coral;
}

.draggable {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px lightgray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">panel without panel--expanded class</div>
<div class="draggable" draggable="true">draggable element</div>
<div class="panel panel--expanded">panel with panel--expanded class</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the `IntersectionObserver` is not the right tool for this task, since the element being dragged is a visual representation of the source element created by the browser - i.e. the actual element stays at its current position. That's why there is no intersection detected by the observer.

You could use the `ondragover` event handler on your node(s) to detect the intersection, like this:

```js
function handleDrag(event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('.panel--expanded')) {
        console.log('OVERLAPPING!');  
    } 
}
```

```css
.panel {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  width: 500px;
}

.panel--expanded {
  background-color: coral;
}

.draggable {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px lightgray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel" ondragover="handleDrag(event)">panel without panel--expanded class</div>
<div class="draggable" draggable="true">draggable element</div>
<div class="panel panel--expanded" ondragover="handleDrag(event)">panel with panel--expanded class</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To be a little bit clearer: At the moment, our drag&drop is solved by https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api. So I do not set the draggable by myself, I just want to know, when an element is overlapping another...Maybe I can add an EventListener for drag and try to detect with the function from four condition, if it is overlapping: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event

Comment: By 'draggable' you mean the element being dragged, right?
For this solution to work you only need to use `ondragover` on any element for which you want to check the intersection. You do not need to access the draggable element in any way.

Comment: Now I see! Thanks, I'll try it out!